# How to apply authorization filter to a api controller in asp.net core mvc application

Tags: session, authorization, session-state, authorize-attribute

The problem is without user login when we hit api url from postman the data is passed to the postman.
But i want to restrict that access from postman when user is logged in only the api url should hit from the postman without login we should restrict it

I have tried by using authorize attribute and can you help by applying authorize attribute